# fnServerParams isn't working for me

Tags: datatables

I need to send custom filters to my server side processing for dataTables.net

I have a drop down which contains dates, after the user has seleted a date, then the tables need to reflect the option they have selected. I can't for the life of me work out why this isn't sending anything:

```
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
aoData.push({"name": "iArchiveYears", "value": $("ddYears option:selected").text()})
```

when I look in firebug, iArchiveYears in there, but empty.

Even hardcoding a value in here instead of the drop down value doesn't work.

Any advice most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$("#ddYears option:selected")`
Instead of
 `$("ddYears option:selected")`.
`#` missing.